# Setting badge value in UITabBarItem in UIViewController

Tags: uikit, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I am adding UITabBarController to the window, and setting the viewControllers property of the UITabBarController to the array of ViewControllers. 
  If i am setting the badge value inside the viewController then its working fine.
  self.tabBarItem.badgeValue = @"3";

But if i am setting the viewControllers property of the UITabBarController to the array of navigation controllers which is having view controller as the rootviewcontroller, then its not setting the badge value.

Any suggestions ??

Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, i got the answer.

```
[[self navigationController] tabBarItem].badgeValue = @"3";
```

Comment: And also equal it to ```nil``` to get rid of the badge.

Comment: have you seen it on badgeValue at initial tabor controller loaded or in that separate tab bar item

Answer (score 17):

Or this:

```
[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber]];
```