# UITabBarItem setBadgeValue:nil throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a tab bar, and I'm trying to remove an item's badge value by setting it to `nil`. However, sometimes, I'm getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. The main thread is suspended after the exception, and I'm `po`ing:

```
(lldb) po [[self.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:2]
<UITabBarItem: 0x17015e980> //no problem with the class itself

(lldb) po [[[self.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:2] setBadgeValue:0]
 nil

(lldb) po [[[self.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:2] setBadgeValue:1]
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

(lldb) po [[[self.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:2] setBadgeValue:0]
 nil
```

This appears to happen randomly, at least, I haven't found a specific pattern yet. However, it doesn't make any sense. Is this a bug?

**UPDATE:** Oops, I tried to set numbers instead of strings in debugger above, where it's normal to throw, but the original problem still applies.

Comment: `nil` is the default value of `badgeValue` as per documentation. So the reason must be somewhere else... you said that you pass a valid string?

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
[[self navigationController] tabBarItem].badgeValue = @"your-value";
```

[Here is the link for your reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850540/setting-badge-value-in-uitabbaritem-in-uiviewcontroller)

Comment: But I can't. It's not the currently selected tab bar item which I'm setting.