# Putting a `UILabel` on one of the `Tabbar` Button

Tags: ios

I want to add a small `Label` which will be having a counter, This Label will be on one of the `TabBar Button's` right top corner, but the `TabBar` is in appdelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. How should i add it?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: see this link may be help with you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337803/how-to-add-small-red-dot-in-uitabbaritem/31338049#31338049

Comment: you can add uilabel as subview of uitabbarbutton class.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks... link will help alot.....

Comment: tanx a lot bro, have a nice day