# How to add badge for bar button?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, badge

I am new for iOS mobile developing.I want to add badge for UIbarbuttonitem.I am added UIbarbuttonitem in UI side.Can you please help me any one.Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684636/how-to-add-badges-on-uibarbutton-item

Comment: I am added in ui side directly.

Comment: You have to customize all for View.

Comment: with out customize any other way is there?

Comment: Not then programmatically as above answer, its working fine

Comment: By using labels it is possible?

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337803/how-to-add-small-red-dot-in-uitabbaritem/31338049#31338049

Comment: yes, take label instead of Button and giver corner Radius of label, So label is also display same of Badge

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Download class from here [UIBarButtonItem-Badge](https://github.com/mikeMTOL/UIBarButtonItem-Badge) and import in your project only **UIBarButtonItem+Badge.h** or **UIBarButtonItem+Badge.m** class in project 
and import in your class

```
#import "UIBarButtonItem+Badge.h"
```

write down only one line for set badge

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.badgeValue = @"5"; //your value
```

> Swift 3

for me, it was not working without **DispatchQueue**

```
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.badgeBGColor = UIColor.red
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.badgeValue = "\(5)"
        }
```

Comment: self.navigationItem.badgeValue=@"3";