# How to show ui tab bar badge when UiTabBarController is having storyboard ids linked up, instead of direct child view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, badge

On my storyboard, I have one main UiTabBarController, which is then having 5 child storyboard ids. Each of the storyboard id is having its child view controllers and it expands.

My question is, when I tried to set badge value at my main UiTabBarController using the code similar like this `tabBarController?.tabBar.items![0].badgeValue = "1"`, it won't work.

However, when I tried connecting my main UiTabBarController to its child view controllers directly (not using storyboard ids), the badge is working. Any idea why this happens? As I don't want to merge all viewcontrollers under one main.storyboard because it could get messy..

Comment: Does tabBarController your root view controller?

Comment: Also you should check if it available: `if let tabBar = self.tabBarController { ... }`

Comment: Yes my main tabBarController is my root view controller, and I've set it as the initial view controller on storyboard as well.. personally I've [tried this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41713963/9088278) and it works well if I am not connecting to storyboard ids

Comment: Try to get your `tabBar` from `appDelegate` dirrectly: `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as! UiTabBarController` and setup budge to it.